# Prove by mathematical induction that $(3n+1)7^n -1$ is divisible by $9$ for integral $n>0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, contest-math, divisibility

$7^n(3n+1)-1=9m$

$S_k = 7^k(3k+1)-1=9P$

$\Rightarrow 7^k(3k+1) = 9P+1$

$S_{k+1} = 7\cdot7^k(3(k+1)+1)-1$

$= 7\cdot7^k(3k+1+3)-1$

$= 7\cdot7^k(3k+1) +21\cdot7^k -1$

$= 7(9P+1)+21\cdot7^k -1$

$= 63P+7+21\cdot7^k -1$

$= 63P+6+21\cdot7^k$

$= 9(7P +2/3+21\cdot7^k/9)$

therefore it is divisible by $9$

So I believe I have done this right but I've ended up with non-integers in the answer which im pretty sure isn't right.
Where have I gone wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You haven't gone wrong, but you haven't finished yet: You need to prove that the quantity $2/3+21\cdot 7^k/9 =(2+7^{k+1})/3$ is itself an integer, i.e., that $3$ divides $7^{k+1}+2$ for any $k$.

Comment: There is a slight variation on induction that deserves to be better known. In this case, calculate the thing for $n=1,2,3.$ Then the induction step is worked for $n+3.$ Cleaner.

Comment: Another approach is to show that $9$ divides $[(3 (n+1) + 1) 7^{n+1} - 1]-[(3 n + 1) 7^n - 1]$.

Comment: $3|(7^{k+1}+2)\Rightarrow 3|(7^{k+2}+14)\Leftrightarrow 3|(7^{k+2}+12+2)\Rightarrow 3|(7^{k+2}+2)$ might be the final step -- one more induction to prove the induction step)

Comment: If the main purpose of your post is to ask for critique of your approach, I think that the tag ([tag:solution-verification]) would be suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost finished.

You assume that 
$S_k = 7^k(3k+1)-1$ is divisible by 9, and therefore divisible by 3.

$S_k = 7^k(3k)+ 7^k-1$ is divisible by 3.

Therefore $7^k-1$ is divisible by 3.

let $3x = 7^k-1$.

$7^k=3x+1$

Then in your final steps:

$=63P+6+21\cdot7^k$

$=63P+6+21(3x+1)$

$=63P+63x+27$

$=9(7P+7x+3)$

Answer (score 2):

Another, less elegant way of proving it is using modular arithmetic. In essence, we show that if
$$7^n(3n+1)-1\equiv0 \mod9$$
And, for the inductive step,
$$7^{n+1}(3(n+1)+1)-1=7^{n+1}(3n+4)-1=7(7^n(3n+1)-1+1+3\cdot7^n)-1$$
Using congruence mod $9$:
$$6+3\cdot7^n\equiv0\mod9$$
For all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_9$, which implies what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 1):

To address your question directly:

You calculations are correct but - as you realized by yourself - the **conclusion** at the end is **still not justified** since there are fractions in "$= 9(7P +2/3+21\cdot7^k/9)$".

So, just go one step back and try to squeeze out factor $9$, for example, as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}63P+6+21\cdot7^k
& = & 63P + 3(2+7^{k+1}) \\
& \stackrel{7^{k+1}=(6+1)^{k+1}=6m+1}{=} & 63P + 3(2+1+6m) \\
& = & 63P + 9(1+2m) \\
& = & 9(7P + 1+2m)
\end{eqnarray}
Now, the conclusion is justified.

Comment: thanks for the response, but how did you get 6m in?

Comment: @Ham_Dog : This is based on the binomial formula:


$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk x^k = 1 + x\cdot n + x^2\binom n2 + \cdots + x^n = 1+x\cdot m$. Now, just plug in $x=6$.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can also  be done WITHOUT INDUCTION Il.
$$(3n+1)7^n-1$$
$$=(3n+1)(6+1)^n-1$$
Where in expension of $(6+1)^n$ , except last two terms rest will be multiple of $6^2$
$$=(3n+1)(36m+6n+1)-1 ; where \,\,m\in I $$
$$=108mn+6n+3n +1-1=108mn+9n , where \,\,m,n \in I $$
$$= 9K , where \,\, K \in I $$

Comment: This is wrong. You are saying that this number is even for all natural numbers $n$, which is clearly wrong if you take odd $n$.

Comment: Where it is assumed to be even

Comment: A multiple of $18$ is always even.

Comment: Got it what you are saying

Comment: Thanks for pointing the same

Comment: Your second last step is wrong. $(3n+1)(36m+6n+1)=108mn+18n^2+3n+36m+6n+1$, the proof becomes correct after that.